# Отфильтровывать неиспользуемые файлы при сборке проекта с помощью Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, frontend

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какой-то плагин для Gulp, который при сборке проекта видит, какие файлы не используются в проекте и не будет их компилировать при сборке в исходящую папку?

Конкретно это касается картинок. Например, в папке app/img 10 картинок, из которых только 5 подключены в проект. Но при сборке в папку build/img попадают все картинки, даже те, которые в проекте не нужны.

Comment: Как насчет https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-delete-unused-images?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko то что нужно! Спасибо!